# How to show this shadow of this kind at the bottom of the box - triagle-ish depth shadow

Tags: css

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vC7R.png)

Look at the shadow at the bottom of the above popup how do I get this type of shadow

```css
body{
  background: rgba(135,206,250, 0.5);
}
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">

</div>
```

Comment: Could you help us and expand upon your question a bit. Would be cool if you describe the effect that you want to have at the end and put it into title and lead line of your question. 

My description would be `triagle`-ish depth shadowbox.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body{
  background: rgba(135,206,250, 0.5);
}

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  background: white;
}


.shadow
{
 position: relative;
}

.shadow:before, .shadow:after
{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 content: "";
 bottom: 25px;
 left: 10px;
 width: 50%;
 top: 80%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #989898;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #989898;
 box-shadow: 0 35px 20px #989898  ;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
 transform: rotate(-10deg);
}

.shadow:after
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(10deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(10deg);
  transform: rotate(10deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="card shadow">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use css `pseudo` element along with `transform: rotate`

Try following snippet.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc
}

.box h3 {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}

.box {
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
}

.shadow:before,
.shadow:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

.shadow:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box shadow">
  <h3>test of the week?</h3>
</div>
```